# Why is my first value not printing correctly but every value following is printing correctly

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

My goal is to obtain the lowest temperature values across 6 different lakes, i'm able to get every value besides the first value (lake superior), how do I get that value to print?

I tried setting initial values of the coldest temps to be the first row of the array so it can compare it with a value that is greater than 0 (no values in the file will be less than 0)

here's the file data that i used for this question, the format of it is year / day / then each lake in order 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADaYffIlMjsZbGMA-85adDg2uXLydshY/view?usp=sharing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
/* variables */
    double alltemps[365][8], coldest[6], coldestday[6], coldestmonth[6];
    int i, j;

/* j = rows, i = columns */

/* open file and assign values to the array */
    FILE*WaterTemperatureData;

    WaterTemperatureData=fopen("WaterTemperatureData.txt", "r");

    for(j=0;j<365;++j)
    {
        for(i=0;i<8;++i)
        {
            fscanf(WaterTemperatureData, "%lf", &alltemps[j][i]);
        }

    }

/* determine coldest temps for each lake */
for(i=2; i<8; ++i)
    {    
        for(j=0; j<365; ++j)
        {
            coldest[i-1] = alltemps[0][i];

            if (alltemps[j][i] < coldest[i-2])
            {
                coldest[i-2] = alltemps[j][i];
                coldestday[i-2] = alltemps[j][1];
            }
        }
    }

/* output statements */
    printf("Coldest Temperature of Lake Superior is %2.2lf on %0.0lf\n", coldest[0],coldestday[0]);
    printf("Coldest Temperature of Lake Michigan is %2.2lf on %0.0lf\n", coldest [1],coldestday[1]);
    printf("Coldest Temperature of Lake Huron is %2.2lf on %0.0lf\n", coldest [2],coldestday[2]);
    printf("Coldest Temperature of Lake Erie is %2.2lf on %0.0lf\n", coldest [3],coldestday[3]);
    printf("Coldest Temperature of Lake Ontario is %2.2lf on %0.0lf\n", coldest [4],coldestday[4]);
    printf("Coldest Temperature of Lake St. Clair is %2.2lf on %0.0lf\n", coldest [5],coldestday[5]);    

return(0);
}
```

For lake superior I expect to get 1.33 on day 72 instead of 0 on day 0

Comment: `for(i=2; i<8; ++i)` seems strange that you start from 2

Comment: You don't seem to ever initialize the values in the arrays, so comparing something to the first element is undefined behavior.

Comment: started from 2 because temperature values start at 2, first two columns are year and days

Comment: So did you mean to have assignment `coldest[i-2] = alltemps[0][i]` maybe? That should be outside the loop anyway. It would also be easier to always start from zero and add 2 when needed.

Comment: doing what you suggested (coldest[i-2] = alltemps[0][i]) just outputs the last value in the lake for all lakes, placing that outside of the loop reports back 0s for everything

Comment: Does your `fscanf` accurately reflect the content of your file?

Comment: yes my 'fscanf' does accurately reflect my file @sjsam

Comment: You are printing `coldest[0]`, but you never assign a value to that element, because your `if (alltemps[j][i] < coldest[i-2])' test is almost certain to never be true.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is my first value not printing correctly (?)

`coldest[i-2]` used before being assign --> *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
for(i=2; i<8; ++i)
  // coldest[2-2] never  assigned
  if (alltemps[j][i] < coldest[i-2])
```